# How can I improve my code for calculating the Nth row of Pascals Triangle while using Memoization and Recursion?

Tags: python, recursion, memoization

I've been revising recursion and decided to use it to calculate rows of Pascals Triangle. I've successfully created a function that generates Pascals Triangle which works for n <= 7 however it is incredibly inefficient. I am aware of the identity for generating Pascals Triangle but I'm not really interested in that. What I'd like is some guidance as to improve the code below.

After about n = 7 it takes a very long time to calculate, which makes me think I have implemented my memoization wrong.

```
count = 0 
def Pascal(n):
    global count
    count += 1 
    pasc_list = [] 
    i = 0 
    j = i+1
    dictionary = {0:[1],1:[1,1]}

    if n in dictionary:
        return dictionary[n]
    else:
        pasc_list.append(1)
        while j < len(Pascal(n-1)):
            pasc_list.append(Pascal(n-1)[i] + Pascal(n-1)[j])
            i += 1 
            j = i + 1 
        pasc_list.append(1)
        dictionary[n] = pasc_list
    return pasc_list
a = Pascal(5)
print(a)
print(count)
```

For n = 5 the number of scopes is already 4694 and when n = 6 the number of scope is 75105 which is a dramatic increase. So if anyone could help me reduce how the rate at which scopes are made, I would be very grateful!

Comment: `dictionary` is a local variable, ie. not shared among invocations, and thus cannot/will not be used for memoization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling a Pascal function three times each iteration (moreover, each of them calls it more and more and more...). Your final complexity is `O(n!)` because of it. Just store the calculation of each Pascal result:

```
count = 0 
def Pascal(n):
    global count
    count += 1 

    pasc_list = [] 
    i = 0 
    j = i+1
    dictionary = {0:[1],1:[1,1]}

    if n in dictionary:
        return dictionary[n]

    else:
        pasc_list.append(1)
        p = Pascal(n-1)  # <-------------------- HERE!!
        while j < len(p):
            pasc_list.append(p[i] + p[j])
            i += 1 
            j = i+1 

        pasc_list.append(1)
        dictionary[n] = pasc_list

    return pasc_list

a = Pascal(7)
print(a)
print(count)
```

will print:

```
[1, 7, 21, 35, 35, 21, 7, 1]
7
```

---

Be VERY accurate with recursion and never call heavy functions in loop-statements (like it: `while j < len(Pascal(n-1)): <-- it is VERY bad idea to write code this way!`). Why it is so slow?

Let's suppose we are calculating Pascal(3):

In P3 we call P2 in `while`. So we are calling P2 for j[0]-index, inside it 2 times and another 3 times in the next iteration (j[1]-index). In each P2-iteration we call P1-iteration another 3 times (and 4th for manual P1-iteration). And we repeat THE WHOLE process 4 times for P4, 16 times for P5 and  more and more and more... It is while your code was so slow.

Comment: That's great thank you! Why does this small change make such a massive difference?

Comment: Cool, no heavy functions, I'll bear that in mind and try and find some documentation about it. Thanks!

Comment: If my answer helped you, I will be appreciated if you will upvote/accept answer. I will add more explanation about recursion now.

Answer (score 1):

To correctly use memoization in Python, use a mutable default argument, normally named `memo`:

```
count = 0 

def Pascal(n, memo={0:[1],1:[1,1]}):
    global count
    count += 1 

    pasc_list = [] 
    i = 0 
    j = i+1

    if n in memo:
        return memo[n]

    else:
        pasc_list.append(1)
        while j < len(Pascal(n-1)):
            pasc_list.append(Pascal(n-1)[i] + Pascal(n-1)[j])
            i += 1 
            j = i+1 

        pasc_list.append(1)
        memo[n] = pasc_list

    return pasc_list

a = Pascal(7)
print(a)
print(count)
```

which outputs:

```
c:\srv\tmp> python pascal.py
[1, 7, 21, 35, 35, 21, 7, 1]
70
```

you should also put the memoization return as the first thing your function does:

```
def Pascal(n, memo={0:[1],1:[1,1]}):
    if n in memo:
        return memo[n]

    global count
    count += 1 

    pasc_list = [] 
    i = 0 
    j = i+1

    pasc_list.append(1)
    while j < len(Pascal(n-1)):
        pasc_list.append(Pascal(n-1)[i] + Pascal(n-1)[j])
        i += 1 
        j = i+1 

    pasc_list.append(1)
    memo[n] = pasc_list

    return pasc_list
```

which outputs:

```
c:\srv\tmp> python pascal.py
[1, 7, 21, 35, 35, 21, 7, 1]
6
```

Comment: Thanks for the style critique, I'll take your recommendations onboard. (y)

Answer (score 0):

Memoization can't make up for a bad algorithm.  And in this case, it doesn't make up for anything.  Consider a cleaned up version of your code with the memoization logic removed:

```
count = 0

def Pascal(n):
    global count

    count += 1

    pasc_list = [1]

    if n > 0:

        i = 0
        j = i + 1

        previous = Pascal(n - 1)

        while j < len(previous):
            pasc_list.append(previous[i] + previous[j])
            i += 1
            j = i + 1

        pasc_list.append(1)

    return pasc_list

a = Pascal(10)

print(a)
print(count)
```

(Neither this solution, nor @thebjorn's nor @vurmux's can reach `Pascal(1000)` with the default Python stack allocation.)  If we time @vurmux's accepted answer, and mine above, looping over every row from 0 to 900:

```
for n in range(900):
    print(Pascal(n))
```

The results are identical:

```
> time python3 no-memoization.py > /dev/null
52.169u 0.120s 0:52.36 99.8%    0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
> time python3 memoization.py > /dev/null
52.031u 0.125s 0:52.23 99.8%    0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
>
```

If we take my no-memoization solution above, and simply add in Python's own `lru-cache` decorator:

```
from functools import lru_cache

count = 0

@lru_cache()
def Pascal(n):
# ...
```

We get a significant (100x) speed up:

```
> time python3 lru_cache.py > /dev/null
0.556u 0.024s 0:00.59 96.6% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
>
```

As we do with @thebjorn's (+1) solution which correctly reuses the dictionary cache instead of reallocating it anew on each call.

When redirected to files, all the outputs are identical.  (Many times I've added `functools:lru-cache` to a function only to discover that it actually slowed it down -- i.e. not a good candidate for this optimization.)

Focus on writing a good algorithm and tune it the best you can.  Then, look into techniques like memoization. But do timings to see if it's really a win or not.